# Print 2 numbers stored in 24-bits in decimal format

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, rfid, bit

An implementation function from the nice little Wiegand library [YetAnotherArduinoWiegandLibrary](https://github.com/paulo-raca/YetAnotherArduinoWiegandLibrary) prints a hexadecimal representation of a facility # & card # (8-bit facility #, 16-bit card #) — 24 bits of a 26-bit stream that comes across the wire.

Example encoded 24-bit number: 7111097 (decimal). Hex equivalent: 6C81B9. The 6C portion is the facility # (decimal: 108). 81B9 is card # (decimal 33209).

This function from the library's example usage serial prints the hexadecimal format of the number:

```
void receivedData(uint8_t* data, uint8_t bits, const char* message) {
    Serial.print(message);
    Serial.print(bits);
    Serial.print("bits / ");
    //Print value in HEX
    uint8_t bytes = (bits+7)/8;
    for (int i=0; i<bytes; i++) {
        Serial.print(data[i] >> 4, 16);  //1st, 3rd, 5th hex digit
        Serial.print(data[i] & 0xF, 16); //2nd, 4th, 6th hex digit
    }
    Serial.println();
}
```

What I've tried to do unsuccessfully so far is to loop over the bits to also serial print the two decimal formatted numbers (facility:card) in the final output form:  **108:33209**

Comment: why do you need to `loop over bits`? ... the `for` loop already manipulates bytes of data

Comment: @jsotola With or without a for loop how do you output the two separate logical numbers in decimal format?

Comment: how do you convert 3 bytes to a single number? .... think about this ... what mathematical process do you follow to convert 4 hundreds , 6 tens and 8 units to 468?

Comment: I wonder why that sample code prints each nibble of a byte separately? Doesn't `Serial.print(255, 16);` output `FF`? So couldn't the inside of the for loop just read `Serial.print(data[i], 16);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code loops from the high order byte to the low order byte, printing each byte as 2 hex digits.

If you want instead to print the first byte as a decimal value, and then the remaining bytes as another decimal value, then do this:

Print byte 0 in base 10:

```
    Serial.print(data[0]);  //first byte
    Serial.print(":");
```

Then loop through the remaining bytes, building a result as a decimal value, and print that:

```
unsigned long total = 0;
for (int i=1; i<bytes; i++) //Skip the first byte
{
    total = total << 8;  //Shift the previous total by 8 bits. 
                         //(The same as multiplying by 256, but faster)
    total += data[i];    //Add in the new value
}
Serial.println(total);
```

The sample code you posted is written to handle a variable number of bytes. The code above does the same thing with decimal results. It's much simpler if you know you will always have 3 bytes or 4 bytes:

For 3 bytes:

```
    Serial.print(data[0]);  //first byte
    Serial.print(":");
    long total = long(data[1])*256 + data[2]);
    Serial.println(long(total);
```

Comment: I wrote the second version of the code using long ints, since I started out with printing an 8-bit value followed by a 24 bit value. If the second value is only 2 bytes (16 bits) you could change the data type to `unsigned int`

Comment: This is great and makes sense of it for me, thank you.